# Одновременная работа с несколькими версиями десктоп приложения

Tags: desktop

Предположим, есть какое-то количество разных версий одного и того же десктоп приложения. В один прекрасный момент, перестал работать какой-то функционал.

Задача: Проверить, а работал ли этот функционал раньше? И если да, то в какой версии он поломался.

Вопрос: Возможно ли это реализовать каким-то способом, который сократил бы время на проверку.

Текущее решение: Выбрано несколько промежуточных билдов и руками идет попытка воспроизвести этот кейс.

Как хотелось бы в идеале: Где-то развернуто N-е количество версий. Кейс выполняется на одном каком-то main билде, но в тоже время идет имитация кейса на остальных билдах. И как итог, в конце получаем статистику, на каких билдах работало, а на каких нет.

Какие будут предложения, товарищи? :)

Comment: Вы не могли бы уточнить OS? в зависмости от неё зависит и само решение.

Comment: а, да. семейство windows. Еще как вариант, возможно есть какое-то record/play решение, типа как Selenium IDE в web, что бы я мог записать действия, сконвертировать это в какой-то файл, powershell script например и через CI запустить его, на разных ВМ.